# Why won't my $(document).ready() and .click() prompts work?

Tags: javascript, prompt

Why don't both of my prompts work? If I delete the second prompt, the first prompt occurs on page load (as desired). The second prompt never works (even if I delete the first prompt). Someone, please save me! :-)

```
// first prompt

var answerOne = prompt("Question?");

$('h1').text(answerOne);

// second prompt

$('#someID').on('click', function() {
    var answerTwo = prompt("Another question?");
    $('h1').text(answerTwo);
};
```

Comment: You haven't loaded jQuery? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last characters (the last line of your js code :)

```
};
```

should be

```
});
```

If You would open up Firebug or Console in other debugger you would saw that. :)

Comment: ugh! yes! thank you. i need to learn how use debugger better properly. lol... thank you :-)